# Cross Database Ownership Chaining fails: not able to access the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, ownership

I have:

- A single Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
- Two databases with some tables: `DB1` and `DB2` (both with the same owner)
- A view in DB1, `DB1.dbo.View1`, that `SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.Table1`
- A role, `ViewRole`, in DB1 granted SELECT permit to the view (no other permissions)
- A Windows user, `DOMAIN\user`, with server role set to `public`, who belongs to DB1's `ViewRole`

When the user tries to SELECT from the view, I get the error:

> The server principal "DOMAIN\user" is not able to access the database "DB2" under the current security context

I have tried (and hopefully succeeded) to activate Cross Database Ownership Chaining using both:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Cross DB Ownership Chaining', '1';RECONFIGURE
```

and

```
EXEC sp_dboption DB1, 'db chaining', 'true'
EXEC sp_dboption DB2, 'db chaining', 'true'
```

To confirm that the setting is made, I run:

```
SELECT name, owner_sid, is_db_chaining_on FROM sys.databases
```

and the result is:

```
name  owner_sid           is_db_chaining_on
DB1   0x0105...DCB510000  1
DB2   0x0105...DCB510000  1
```

So, why won't the user be able to SELECT from the view? There will be no error if the view only selects from a table within DB1.

Anyone has any suggestion as to what I might have missed or misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The windows user has to have access to both databases to be able to use cross database ownership chaining.

You should also disable the option on server level for security and only enable the option in the databases.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks JodyT! That was exactly it. Once I added the user to DB2 it worked like a charm. And I will also remove the server level option; I just added it to be completely sure it was active.